# Why combination with repetition doesn't use the same formula as unitary coefficient equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Unitary coefficient equation uses the formula

$$ x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k = m $$

$$ C(m + k - 1, k - 1) $$

(considering $x$ can be $0$, i.e solutions in positive integers)

But for combination with repetition, my book says that the formula is $C(m + k - 1, k)$ (note it is not $k-1$) and says that it is equivalent to proposing the problem as:

$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k = m$$

The weird thing is that in the example for combination with repetition is exactly the way of a equation with unitary coefficients.

Example: How many different sets of three coins can be made if each coin can be 10, 25, 50 cents or 1 dollar.

It says that this can be thought as $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 3$

In this case is $C(6, 3)$ which seems to correlate with the first theorem.

But another example says "In a library there 20 math books each one with unlimited quantity. How many elections of 10 books can be done if repetitions are allowed?"

And puts as answer $C(29, 10)$ instead of $C(29, 9)$

As my thinking is that it should be $C(20 + 10 - 1, 10 - 1)$

I am a bit confused.

Idiot-proof answer is much appreciated.

Comment: The number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = m$ in the *nonnegative* (not positive) integers is $\binom{m + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{m + k - 1}{m}$.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Thanks, yes you are right. So text book wanted to complicate things. So the library problem has the wrong solution then?

Comment: Did you mean how many selections of $10$ books can be done if repetitions are allowed?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig yes typo, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = m$$
in the *nonnegative* (not positive) integers is 
$$\binom{m + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{m + k - 1}{m}$$
The author of your book seems to be using the formula
$$\binom{m + k - 1}{m}$$
in which case $\binom{m + k - 1}{k}$ is a rather unfortunate typographical error.

> How many different sets of three coins if each coin can be 10 cents, 25 cents, 50 cents, or one dollar?

There are four different types of coins, so $k = 4$.  A total of three coins are selected, so $m = 3$. Thus, we obtain the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 3$$
Our formula yields 
$$\binom{m + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{6}{3} = \binom{3 + 4 - 1}{3} = \binom{m + k - 1}{m}$$

> In a library, there are $20$ books, each one with unlimited quantity.  How many selections of $10$ books can be done if repetitions are allowed?

In this case, there are $20$ types of books, so $k = 20$.  A total of $10$ books are selected, so $m = 10$.  Our formula yields
$$\binom{m + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{10 + 20 - 1}{20 - 1} = \binom{29}{19} = \binom{29}{20} = \binom{10 + 20 - 1}{20} = \binom{m + k - 1}{m}$$
where
$$\binom{29}{19} = \binom{29}{10}$$
since 
$$\binom{n}{j} = \binom{n}{n - j}$$

Your confusion stems from what appears to be a typographical error in the text and, in the second problem, from distinguishing between $k$ and $m$.

Comment: Yes I confused the k and m because they were switched in order, thanks a lot!